# Best Way to Remove a Node from a Vector Based Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search-tree

I have a function called:

```
bool remove_one(E itm)
```

Where it takes an element from that array (tree), and tries to remove it, whilst keeping the order of the Binary Search Tree. If this was a node based BST, I would have no problem. But I am very unclear on how to do this with a vector based BST. Can someone please guide me in the right direction on where to at least begin attempting this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

How about vector[i] = null
and the if it's necessary you can resize the vector